# Array value not incrementing properly

Tags: c++, qt, multidimensional-array, increment, issue-tracking

I have mainList of type `Qlist<QStringList>` to which a set 5 of QStringLists named newList is being added. The 7th index of a QStringList named List has an integer value( price). For each of the 5 iterations I want to increase the price value by 10.

i.e the 1st newList has a value of 110 in the 7th index, 2nd newList has a value of 120 in the 7th index, and the the last(5th) newList should have a value 150.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int Price;

    Price=100;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<List.size();j++){
            if(j==7){
              Price+=10;
             QString priceString=QString::number(Price);
             newList<<priceString;
           }
            else{
               newList<<List[j];
            }
        }

        mainList<<newList;
    }
    ui->label->setText(mainBuyList[0][7]);
    ui->label_2->setText(mainBuyList[1][7]);
    ui->label_3->setText(mainBuyList[2][7]);
    ui->label_4->setText(mainBuyList[3][7]);
    ui->label_5->setText(mainBuyList[4][7]);
}
```

But when I click the button all the labels print only 110! How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must clear newList after `mainList<<newList;`